# CSS :not and :last-of-type combined

Tags: css, css-selectors

I’m looking for a way to target the last of a certain type, but exclude the very last child that has a class name (if it exists). So I tried this:

```
p:not(.last):last-of-type{color:red}
```

to target the **two** in this markup:

```
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p class="last">three</p>
```

I was thinking that it would first select all P’s that doesn’t have the class "last", then filter out the last of those. But I’m obviously wrong here. Is there any other way?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/365t5mew/

Comment: You can exclude the `<p .last>` from the set, but the `<p>two</p>` will never be `last-of-type`, because it actually considers the dom, not your selection.

Comment: It works excluding the way select the last p if it isn't `.last` as @Christoph notes

Comment: I think you may need JavaScript to do this.

Comment: The css selectors can be combined, but they don't filter the results to the next selector. Instead, they both act as a `&&` condition together